# Abstract a polymorphic 'save' on a model

Tags: laravel-4

I have a polymorphic record I want to create.

This works

```
$user->logs()->create(['message' => 'message', 'failed' => false]);
```

But how do I convert that to something like this:

```
$user->logs()->logSuccess('message');
```

In my logs model class I tried this:

```
public function scopeLogSuccess($query, $message)
{
    $this->create(['message' => $message, 'failed' => false]);
}
```

But nothing happens. The query runs - but no data is inserted in the database and no error is thrown.

I also tried this:

```
public function scopeLogSuccess($query, $message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->failed = false;
    $this->save();
}
```

A "record" is saved in the Logs table - but it doesnt have the "loggable_id" or "loggable_type" that should be generated on a polymorphic relationship - they are just blank.

Comment: Elaborate on "But neither seem to work?" - any errors or just unexpected results?

Comment: Sorry - question updated with extra info.

Comment: lol... why did someone downvote this question? Its seems like a valid question to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to extend the `MorphTo` class and add your custom methods - I don't see an easy way to achieve this. I would recommend just adding the `logSuccess` etc method on your user model.

Comment: Hmmm... but then I'd need to but logSuccess into my other models that also save logs...

Comment: ...or maybe I make a trait Loggable or something - and attach that to the loggable models...